# Python Ternary Operator Comparison: `a if test else b` v.s. `test and a or b`

Tags: python, lambda, conditional-operator

As far as I know, Python have two `Ternary Operators`:

1. a if test else b
2. test and a or b

It seems that they achieve the same goal, and both can be used in lambda function.

```
>>> (lambda x: True if x > 0 else False)(5)
True
>>> (lambda x: True if x > 0 else False)(-5)
False

>>> (lambda x: x > 0 and True or False)(5)
True
>>> (lambda x: x > 0 and True or False)(-5)
False
```

**Question**

Is there any case that we should use one instead of the other?

Comment: No, `... and ... or ...` is **not** a ternary operator. That is *two* **binary** operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can produce different results:

```
In [30]: (lambda x: x and 0 or 1)(True)
Out[30]: 1

In [31]: (lambda x: 0 if x else 1)(True)
Out[31]: 0
```

Comment: Thanks @unutbu! Yes, the and-or trick only works if `a` (in `test and a or b`) is **true**.  `a if test else b` seems to be a much reliable and cleaner way to perform ternary conditional calculation :-)